# UITableView not pushing the Detail View!

Tags: iphone, uitableview, pushviewcontroller

losing sleep over this issue

My app hierarchy is ListVC1-->ListVC2-->DetailVC. [Working perfect]

and... SearchListVC-->DetailVC (the same DetailVC as above) [Issue is in this model]

The code in SearchListVC is almost same as ListVC2, with a difference that it contains a SearchBar, instead of a navigationBar, on top.

Also, please note that I am able to present the DetailVC as a ModalView, it is push that is not happening... the cell remains highlighted.

Here is the didselectrow code

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
// Navigation logic may go here. Create and push another view controller.
if (indexPath.row<[smses count]) {
    WebSMSDetailViewController *detailViewController = [[WebSMSDetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"WebSMSDetailViewController" bundle:nil];

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];

    detailViewController.smsList = allWebSMSes;
    detailViewController.smsIndex = indexPath.row;
    [detailViewController populateDetails];

    [detailViewController release];
}
else {
    if (indexPath.row<totalSMSes) {
        pageNumber++;
        [self loadNotes];
    }
}}
```

I think the problem is somewhere else. 
I have been googling for quite a while but couldn't understand the solutions posted, so please be a little descriptive... beginner here!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose the problem is that, you dont have a navigation controller in the SearchListVC.
Like you wrote,

> it contains a SearchBar, instead of a navigationBar, on top

Use a navigation controller with the SearchListVC and I think your problem is solved.

Cheers

Comment: how do I do that? and never done such things for any other UITableViewController classes, they just work & have the navigationBar at top... anyways... how do I do that?

Comment: I dont want to be rude but u need to work a little more on basics. You create an object of UINavigationController and init its root with the UITableViewController and instead of showing UITableViewController's view show UINavigationController's view. Check the designated initializers for UINavigationController.

Comment: There's nothing rude in that... I am still in primitive phase. And the thing you are mentioning about pushing a view using a NavCon, I have been doing it many a times.. esp while presenting modal views... Here the thing confusing me was that SearchVC was coming through TabBar, not through any other view... But still I drilled more after reading ur comment... and got it working... had to add NavCon to TabBar Controller... Thanks man... Cheers Mr Bond!

Answer (score 0):

You just create/use @property for the navigationBar 
or u have to place the Navigationbar on the top of the view and place your search bar on the bottom of the navigationBar